# How to make multiple dialog in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    $(function() {  
        $("#editdialog" + i).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            hieght: 200,
            width: 700,
            modal: true
        });
        $("#EditButton" + i)
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                $("#editdialog" + i).dialog("open");
            }); 
    });
}
```

What is the problem with above javascript code ?

Comment: What is the problem in making an effort to understand what the code is doing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)